# Managing Azure Storage from VS 2013

Tags: azure, azure-storage, visual-studio-2013

I've been following the progress of VS 2013 as its progressed through its releases (Beta, RC, and now GA) and have had an overall positive feeling about the release. Today, I spent the day working entirely in the new version (GA Premium) to ensure that it provides all of the basic functionality needed by my team prior to adoption.

It works well for general dev tasks - given several of my favorite extensions haven't been ported yet - but while attempting to administer our Azure storage from within the IDE it appears to be removed from the previous release.

While in VS2012's Server Explorer, I'm able to link to Azure account to discover all of my top level objects - Cloud Services, Service Bus, Storage, and VMs. Now within VS2013 - following the same setup procedures from the previous version - I only see Mobile Services, SQL Databases, and Web Sites under the Windows Azure node of Server Explorer.

After a little googling I found little insight or even others asking the same thing (since GA) so I'm starting to wonder if it's just me or if this is the way it'll be from now on??? Can anyone confirm and/or provide evidence from Microsoft indicating that this is intentional?

Comment: I don't know about different editions having different features, but I just loaded VS2013 Ultimate RTM and see Storage under Server Explorer/Azure, and was able to add a storage account like always.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Installing the Windows Azure SDK should give you all of the features you're looking for.  You can find directions here: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/visual-studio-2013/ for using the current version of the SDK with the VS 2013 GA release.